# Having trouble adding multiple query params to /v3/messages api

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm having issues trying to filter by multiple params to get all messages from sendgrid;

```js
const queryParams = {
    // "query": "status=\"not_delivered\"", // works
    limit: 20,
    // query: "status=\"not_delivered\"+last_event_time=\"2017-11-07T23:13:58Z\"", // doesn't work
};
const request = {
    url: "/v3/messages",
    method: "GET",
    qs: queryParams,
};
const [, body] = await client.request(request);
```

Can someone help me find what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that is not late, you can separate your queries params with `AND`

```js
const queryParams = {
    query: "status=\"not_delivered\" AND last_event_time=\"2017-11-07T23:13:58Z\"",
    limit: 20,
};
const request = {
    url: "/v3/messages",
    method: "GET",
    qs: queryParams,
};
const [, body] = await client.request(request);
```

You can see more options in the [documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api).

And the keywords and operators [here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api#keywords-and-operator-reference)